# VLOOKUP function not returning correct value, Index Match also incorrect. User Error?

Tags: excel, sorting, indexing, excel-formula, match

Working in Excel 2019. In the same realm as one of my previous questions, I'm working with a database that I'm trying to look through via functions to get my values. The VLOOKUP tool worked well for going through the time-table to find the value I need, but it's not working when I'm trying to find RPM as the look-up value. Here's the gist of the data.

We have Time(sec, A:A in "PPT_156Data" sheet), RPM (B:B in same sheet), and Pressure (Bar, C:C in same sheet).

From the graph, you can see that we ramp to 8000RPM over the course of around 60 seconds, and then ramp down to 0RPM over the next 30. Test times WILL vary and rates WILL vary from pump-to-pump, as each one will give different data values based on the pump. That's why, say, 1000RPM will not be in the same spot every time.

I'm trying to find the RPM at 1000 intervals up to 8000 and report out the pressure at said intervals.

Here's what I tried so far, with imagery as well.

'Disregard if you see W25 for S25, I had just been trying multiple things
First, I attempted the same VLOOKUP code I had done for the time-table prior

```
    =VLOOKUP(S25,PPT156_Data!B:C,2,TRUE)  'S25 being lookup value
```

This worked fine, UP UNTIL it hit a particular spot. For some reason, as soon as it tries to find an approximate match for 6663RPM, it faults out and gives incorrect data. From then on, all the way to 8000RPM, it will ONLY give the result of 0.139BAR. I have no clue why. Trying to find that value in the return array gives multiple results, but it's not like it's the ONLY value left.

So, I tried to do a wildcard for it with the following code

```
    =VLOOKUP("*"&S25&"*",PPT156_Data!B:C,2,FALSE)   'Attempted both False and True states
```

Gave N/A for both of the values. Not sure if I'm entering in the wildcard incorrectly here. The decimal places that the RPM can go to ranges between 2-5 (hundredths to hundred-thousandths, IE 7000.00750)

I then thought maybe an Index Match would work.

```
    =INDEX(PPT156_Data!B:C,MATCH(S25,PPT156_Data!B:B,-1),2)
```

Tried that in wildcard format too, returned nothing. So, I decided to see if I could even match a value for RPM with the following attempts

```
    =MATCH(S25,PPT_Data156!B:B,-1)
```

This gave nothing. HOWEVER, when setting the match specification to 1, it gives the very last row in the data set. So, I decided to find a value in column B, and attempt to match with it exactly.

```
    =MATCH(7000.07,PPT_Data156!B:B,0)
```

This also returned nothing. Even though, you can see in my images, that the value is ABSOLUTELY there. SIGFIG shows it's 7000.1 but trust me, it's 7000.07. So that sort of threw me for a loop. Figuring maybe there was a different error and grasping at straws, tried another Index Match formula, this time subtracting the lookup value in an attempt to get it extremely close and absolute value/min it

```
    =INDEX(PPT156_Data!C:C,MATCH(MIN(ABS(PPT156_Data!B:B-S25)),ABS(PPT156_Data!B:B-S25),1))
```

I'm at a loss. I'm not sure if because the rate ramps up and down, thus not being in ascending order, is causing a problem? I can't change that. I am thinking I may need to create a macro for this in some way? Maybe a helper table? But I can't even FIND the match value to create a helper table. Any help at all would be VERY appreciative.
Thank you for your time looking at my post.

[image: MatchIssue]
[image: MatchIssue2]
[image: MatchIssue3]
[image: VLOOKUPIssue]
[image: VLOOKUPIssueWildcard]
[image: IndexMatchIssue]
[image: IndexMatchIssue]

Comment: Can't fault your effort but I think you would benefit from posting an [mcve].

Comment: @SJR The last time I posted something like this, I didn't have enough detail. Thus, the amount I put in this time. Also got called out for lack of imagery. Posted imagery. I'm also showing the code I tried and my attempts to fix. But, to make it concise, I could try this.

VLOOKUP isn't returning the value I need. Out of an array ranging from 0-8000, from the 6663 point and up, it constantly returns the same value in the reference row it's trying to grab from. Tried multiple iterations, and even attempted to match a value exactly. Can't match exact value, even though it's there.

Comment: Tried the following codes

`=VLOOKUP(S25,PPT156_Data!B:C,2,TRUE)`
`=VLOOKUP("*"&S25&"*",PPT156_Data!B:C,2,FALSE)`
`=INDEX(PPT156_Data!B:C,MATCH(S25,PPT156_Data!B:B,-1),2)`
`=MATCH(S25,PPT_Data156!B:B,-1)`
` =MATCH(7000.07,PPT_Data156!B:B,0)`
`=INDEX(PPT156_Data!C:C,MATCH(MIN(ABS(PPT156_Data!B:B-S25)),ABS(PPT156_Data!B:B-S25),1))`

Each time I get the same value above 6663. I am unable to match the value 7000.07 exactly when looking for it, unsure why. Since I can't match, I imagine I can't find the corresponding value in the reference array I'm trying to get from.

Comment: Vlookup(...,True) and Match(...,-1) require that the lookup data be sorted in ascending order.  If you have it XLOOKUP should work using -1

Comment: I'm assuming that there may be a duplicate value or something that is causing an issue as well, as it's possible for the RPM to duplicate. I see two values for 7000.07, however, when setting it to try and match via -1, it still doesn't work. Doesn't work for direct match, doesn't for 1. Mostly trying to get some form of information as to WHAT I can try to find this. I'm open to almost anything.

Comment: @ScottCraner I though XLOOKUP isn't available for Excel 2019?

Comment: It is not, I missed that comment in your wall of text.

Comment: @ScottCraner Apologies for said wall of text. Is there any other function/formula combination that could possibly work to find this? I feel as though I may need to work in VBA to get this to operate solely because Excel 2019 is limiting me. I don't think I can do a helper table? If I transcribe the data to ascending, I could find the values, but I wouldn't have the accurate corresponding pressure value because of the change.

Comment: I'm trying to get my head round this a bit, but what I can see is you're trying to match the value in the whole of column B but the values of 7000 are repeated several times, so you're likely just matching on the first occurrence. Are you needing to also match the value in column A to narrow the range in B?

Comment: @JoeJ Column B has my RPM values. Column C has pressure correlating to said RPM. Column A is the time that has passed since beginning of the test. I'm trying to locate a specific RPM value, and retrieve its corresponding pressure value. However, due to a scan rate and it jumping around in RPM, it's possible that the RPM can duplicate. But even then, I'm not matching on first occurrence without explicitly finding that value manually and putting it as the lookup value. I can't do that, the value will change from test-to-test, so I need a variable lookup value. I'm not sure what could work here.

Comment: Specifically up at the 6663 point, it starts duplicating. Prior to that, VLOOKUP I was using was finding values that I found acceptable for my correlation. But as soon as it hit 6663 for RPM lookup, that point to 8000 then would ONLY reference a pressure value of 0.139, every time, at every RPM afterwards.

Comment: You can try: `=INDEX(PPT156_Data!C:C,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(PPT156_Data!B$1:B$10000)/(MIN(ABS(7000-PPT156_Data!B$1:B$10000))=ABS(7000-PPT156_Data!B$1:B$10000)),1))`  It will return the closest match.  Replace the two `7000` with the value you are looking for.

Comment: @ScottCraner Hey Scott, thank you for the code! I tried it but it's only returning the first value in the column each time. Not sure what I'm doing wrong on it. It is at least referencing the pressure column now. Is it possible that when subtracting that 7000 (or whatever value I'm looking for) it's not completing a portion and just finding the closest match to 0 at that point in the RPM column? Also, opened a dialog box to select the file. Selected said data file and had it reference the data sheet twice. Not sure if I had something incorrect there. Thanks again for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming that you want the first pressure reading when the RPM hits above each 1000 interval. I got to a solution but feels a bit complex.

```
=index(C:C,1/max(iferror(1/(row(B:B)*(B:B>E12)),Null)))
```

Breaking this down, we create a boolean array where the RPM hits above the interval

```
=B:B>E12
```

and then we multiple this by the array of the rows of column B

```
row(B:B)*(B:B>E12)
```

which gives us an array of the row numbers when the RPM is above E12 but also zero for all the ones that do not.

```
=iferror(1/(row(B:B)*(B:B>E12)),Null)
```

We then force an error with the zeros by dividing and replace with null. We get the max since we inverse the row numbers and then inverse again to get the row number back.

```
 =index(C:C,1/max(iferror(1/(row(B:B)*(B:B>E12)),Null)))
```

[Excel working screenshot][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhcaX.png

Comment: Hey Hence, this is EXACTLY what I needed! Works perfectly. I was attempting something different which SEEMS to be working but nowhere near as well as yours.

`=INDEX(PPT156_Data!D:D,MATCH(6995.217,PPT156_Data!B:B,0)+(LOOKUP(6995.217,PPT156_Data!B:B)<>6995.217))`

This worked as long as I set it as an exact match for the lookup, still couldn't get a wildcard to work for it. BUT, my colleagues and I were going to write in VBA a function to round to the nearest integer and then lookup based on that.  But this saves us from having to do that. Thank you!!